# XeLaTeX cannot find bold version of URW Palladio L

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have downloaded and installed **URW Palladio L** which has become the free and open source variant of URW Palladio. I am using this font in my LaTeX by using XeLaTeX. XeLaTeX, however, does not find the bold font if it is needed.

I have created a minimal example to demonstrate my problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{URW Palladio L}

\begin{document}    
I am regular URW Palladio L.
\textbf{I am bold URW Palladio L, but XeLaTeX cannot find me.}
{\setmainfont{URW Palladio L Bold} I am bold URW Palladio L, however, I was forced to do that.}    
\end{document}
```

After rendering this looks like so.

[image: Rendering that shows how the regular font works, the typical bold one is not found, and if the font is selected manually it works again]

As you can see, it only works if I select the bold version manually. I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/URWPalladioL(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/URWPalladioL(0)/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

While the font is there, it is not found by XeLaTeX. If I execute `fc-list | grep "URW Palladio L"` on my Ubuntu machine I get the following result:

```
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052023l.pfb: URW Palladio L:style=Italic
/home/platzhirsch/.local/share/fonts/urw-palladio-l-roman.ttf: URW Palladio L:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052004l.pfb: URW Palladio L:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052003l.pfb: URW Palladio L:style=Roman
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052024l.pfb: URW Palladio L:style=Bold Italic
```

What could be the reason for that mismatch, respectively what could I do to investigate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I have finished writing the question I directly found the solution and I think it's certainly worth sharing:

The problem is indicated in the grepped output of `fc-list`. The URW Palladio L regular font is listed twice. One time in `/usr/share` and then again in the local home folder in `.local/share`. The local font interfers with the system wide font.

After I deleted `urw-palladio-l-roman.ttf` in `/home/platzhirsch/.local/share/fonts` it works and XeLaTeX finds the appropriate fonts.